# ImportError: No module named alc Python

Tags: python, installation

I'm need to inject option 18 to a DHCPv6 traffic, I found this code, [source](https://documentation.nokia.com/html/0_add-h-f/93-0098-HTML/7750_SR_OS_Triple_Play_Guide/Appendix-Python.pdf),

```
from alc import dhcpv6

import struct

packet = dhcpv6.get_relaymsg()# Extract the original DHCPv6 packet within LDRA.

 

msgType = ord(packet.msg_type) # Get the message type.

ia_na = packet.get_iana()   # Store the IA-NA option for further processing later on.

ia_pd = packet.get_iapd()   # Store the IA-PD option for further processing later on.
 

if msgType == 3: # If the message in the LDRA packet is DHCPv6 Request, insert the lease related times in address/prefic options.

 

    ia_na[0][1] = '\x00\x00\x07\xd0'# Set the renew time (T1) in IA-NA to 2000sec. 

    ia_na[0][2] = '\x00\x00\x0b\xb8'# Set the rebind time (T2) in IA-NA to 3000sec.

    ia_na[0][3][5][0][1] = '\x00\x00\x0f\xa0'  # Set the preferred time in IA-NA to
                                        # 4000sec.

    ia_na[0][3][5][0][2] = '\x00\x00\x0f\xa0'# Set the valid time in IA-NA to 4000sec.

    packet.set_iana(ia_na) # Update the stored packet with the new values for IA-NA.

 

    ia_pd[0][1] = '\x00\x00\x07\xd0'# Set the renew time (T1) in IA-PD to 2000sec.

    ia_pd[0][2] = '\x00\x00\x0b\xb8'# Set the rebind time (T2) in IA-PD to 3000sec.

    ia_pd[0][3][26][0][0] = '\x00\x00\x0f\xa0'  # Set the preferred time in IA-PD to
                                        # 4000sec.

    ia_pd[0][3][26][0][1] = '\x00\x00\x0f\xa0'# Set the valid time in IA-PD to 4000sec.

    packet.set_iapd(ia_pd) # Update the stored packet with the new values for IA-PD.

    dhcpv6.set_relaymsg(packet) # Insert the packet in the LDRA message.
```

but when I run it I got this error:

```
    from alc import dhcpv6

ImportError: No module named 'alc'
```

the problem is that when I tried to install this module I couldn't find it, I installed this package `dhcp-leases-0.1.6.tar.gz` but it didn't solve the problem.
where can I find the `alc` module ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **alc** — The SR OS-provided packages provide access to various ESM
> objects such as DHCPv4, DHCPv6 or RADIUS packets.

Found [here](https://documentation.nokia.com/html/0_add-h-f/93-0098-HTML/7750_SR_OS_Triple_Play_Guide/Appendix-Python.pdf) on page 3 of 42 in the pdf.

It seems that the alc module is included in SR OS. So you'll need to run this python code using [Nokia's SR OS](https://www.nokia.com/networks/products/service-router-operating-system/)

EDIT:
Reading the documentation a little bit more, it seems that this PDF is part of the SR OS manual. Thus the use of the alc module outside of the aforementioned operationg system is probably not possible.